# GSAP pause animation in a function

Tags: gsap

I have a set of buttons that when clicked show a sort of pop up and some simple animations.  Each pop up contain the same animations for most of the content.  Each pop up also has its own sets of animations so I have done the following to get this to work correctly.

```
$gridTitles.click(function() {
  const tl     = new TimelineMax();
  const $pop   = $(this).next('.grid__pop');
  const $chars = $pop.find(".grid__pop-title span");
  const $items = $pop.find(".grid__pop-list li");
  const func   = $(this).data("graphic-function");

  tl.set($pop, {
    autoAlpha: 0,
    display: 'block',
    scale: .5
  })
  .to($pop, 1, {
    autoAlpha: 1,
    scale: 1,
    ease: Power2.easeInOut
  })
  .staggerFrom($chars, 0.01, {
    autoAlpha: 0,
    ease: Power2.easeIn
  }, 0.1)
  .add(graphicAnimation[func])
  .staggerFrom($items, 0.8, {
    autoAlpha: 0,
    rotationX: 90,
    ease: Power2.easeOut
  }, .8);

  return tl;
});
```

This runs my pop up code and also using the .add function I call another function that runs the specific animation for the pop up based on a data attribute matching the name of a function in an object.

```
const graphicAnimation = {

  graphicServer: function() {
    const tl = new TimelineMax();
    const $server = $(".graphic-server__server");
    const $one    = $(".graphic-server__one");
    const $two    = $(".graphic-server__two");
    const $three  = $(".graphic-server__three");

    return tl.to($server, 1, {
      autoAlpha: 1,
      xPercent: "0",
      ease: Power2.easeInOut
    })
    .to($one, 1, {
      autoAlpha: 1,
      xPercent: "0",
      ease: Power2.easeInOut
    })
    .to($two, 1, {
      autoAlpha: 1,
      xPercent: "0",
      ease: Power2.easeInOut
    })
    .to($three, 1, {
      autoAlpha: 1,
      xPercent: "0",
      ease: Power2.easeInOut
    })
  },
  // more functions
}
```

This works great depending on which button is clicked the correct function is called in the object and my animations run.  The problem now is that some of these animations are looping and when I close the popup I can't pause them.

Using something like the following I tried to accomplish this

```
$gridCloses.click(function() {
  const tl  = new TimelineMax();
  const $pop = $(this).parents(".grid__pop");
  const func   = $(this).parents('.grid__pop').siblings('.grid__title').data("graphic-function");

  graphicAnimation[func].pause();

  return tl.to($pop, 1, {
    autoAlpha: 0,
    scale: .5,
    display: 'none'
  });
});
```

But calling `graphicAnimation[func].pause();` isn't going to work as pause() is a function on the returned timeline from that function. How can I access the current running function and pause / kill it.

Answer (score 0):

So I thought this out and just need to store the timelines in their own object as well

```
const graphicTimeLines = {
  graphicServer : new TimelineMax(),
  graphicType: new TimelineMax()
}
```

so with that in my closing action I can do something like the following to completely reset my loops and have the timeline be available to be called again.

```
graphicTimeLines[func].pause().progress(0).kill();
graphicTimeLines[func] = new TimelineMax();
```